# Code Igniter Left outer Join

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, syntax

So this is the query I am not sure how to write on code igniter. I want to put my "And" statement before the where. The query works, but I do not know the syntax of it in code igniter. Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

```
Select c.c_id, c.c_name, p.phone_no FROM Company AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone AS p
ON p.p_flex_id=c.c_id
AND p.g_id'='1' AND p.ct_id='3'
WHERE 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by _syntax in Codeignter_? Do you mean [**ActiveRecord**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) or the PHP syntax?

Comment: `p.g_id'='1'` is this a typo or you left that `'` before the equal sign? Besides try to put some parenteshis like `ON (p.p_flex_id=c.c_id
AND p.g_id='1' AND p.ct_id='3')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think with ActiveRecord sintax it could be something like that

```
$this->db->select('Company.c_id, Company.c_name, Phone.phone_no')
   ->from('Company')
   ->join('Phone','Phone.p_flex_id=Company.c_id AND Phone.ct_id=3','left outer' )
   ->where(1);
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate query with `db` class and pass `LEFT OUTER` param in `join` method, see below

```
$this->db->select("c.c_id, c.c_name, p.phone_no")
->join("Phone AS p", "p.p_flex_id=c.c_id AND p.g_id'='1' AND p.ct_id='3'", "LEFT OUTER")
->get("Company AS c")
```